# How to write CSS for outline in button as class="btn btn-outline-primary" not working?

Tags: css

I have the following code for Button

Example 1

```
<button type='submit' class = 'btn btn-success' name='submit'>Logout<i style='margin-left:10px;' class='fas fa-sign-out-alt' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>
```

Example 2

```
<div class='btn-group'>                            
<button type="submit" name="showNotBillableEntry" class="btn btn-primary" style='border-radius: 8px; '><i class='fa fa-eye' style='margin-right:10px;'></i>Not Billable Entries
</button>
</div>
```

But when i changes the class `btn btn-primary` to `btn btn-outline-primary`, button become grey not outline as in bootstrap reference explained. Earlier they were green in color due to class `btn btn-primary`.

I want to use this `<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>` but it is not working.

Referring bootstrap - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

I need help in css becoz the bootstrap link says to use `type='button'` in place of `type='submit'` but i can't use that as this button contain some data to be submitted to php server.

I have also included links which are needed for use in bootstrap.

Comment: instead of class="btn btn-primary use class="btn btn-outline-primary"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="font-size:30px;">Primary</button>
```

Comment: but i can't change the `type='submit'` to `type='button'`

Comment: yes it worked but it made the size of button smaller

Comment: May be due to repeated use of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`?

Comment: Of what size you want?

Comment: Actually all button along with text changed to small size of 75% view

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your present output and your desired output?

Comment: By default it will take the small size due to bootstrap. You can specify your custom css. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this as per your need. This is directly from the [bootstrap's stylesheet](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)

```
.btn-outline-primary{color:#007bff;border-color:#007bff}
.btn-outline-primary:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#007bff;border-color:#007bff}
.btn-outline-primary.focus,
.btn-outline-primary:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,123,255,.5)}
.btn-outline-primary.disabled,
.btn-outline-primary:disabled{color:#007bff;background-color:transparent}
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,.show>
.btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle{color:#fff;background-color:#007bff;border-color:#007bff}
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,.show>
.btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,123,255,.5)}
```

Comment: Thanks @Janak, i was late to see it